# How to make an input field not editable through text

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm using the react [FormControl](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/forms/) like so:

```
<FormControl
            type={"datetime-local"}
            value={field.value}
            onChange={field.onChange}
            isInvalid={props.errors[name]}
          />
          {form.errors[name] && (
            <div className="custom-invalid-feedback">{form.errors[name]}</div>
          )}
</FormGroup>
```

But it's editable by text input. I want it so that the date can only be selected from the dropdown and not by entering text. Is there a way to do this with FormControl, or is there another form that works with Formik that can be used?

Comment: did you tried to add the **disabled** flag to the component?

Answer (score 0):

There is officially no such attribute that would help you with your use case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes

Nore has the Form.Control component anything helpful: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/form-control/#form-control-props

So what you need to do is to take control of rendering the input and the widget:

- Define a state for the datetime value
- Place a toggle which shows/hides some date/datetime widget
- When widget sets a value, set the state as well
- Reflect this state on the toggle label/title

I have set up a sandbox with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-shadow-nwi877.
I'm using "react-datetime" library as an example, but it's up to you what widget library you want to use. For the toogle, Dropdown component is used.